# Fetch foreign key table data

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core

While fetching data from dbcontext this.dbcontext.JobDetails.GetAll().
Here I also need data from a foreign key table that is likes for current `jobDetails`.

```
public class Like
{
    public int LikeId { get;  set; }
    public JobDetails JobDetails { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("JobDetailFK")]
    public int JobDetailId { get; set; }
}
public class JobDetails
{
    [Key]
    public int JobDetailId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Like> Likes { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Entity Framework 6 you can do it like this:

```
using (DatabaseContext context = new DatabaseContext()) {
    return context.JobDetails.Include(x => x.Likes).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It is working for single list object. But i have two least in my JobDetails.

Comment: You should then lookup ThenInclude and multilevel includes using select, with those you should be able to fetch data in every given relations

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the answer provided, you can also get several lists and even nested data.

```
List<item> items = db.mainData
    .Where(x => x.parentId == id)
    .Include(x => x.moreData)
            .ThenInclude(acc => acc.field)
    .Include(x => x.evenMoreData)
            .ThenInclude(acc => acc.field)
    .ToList();
```